# O que estou errando neste require?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, require

Criei uma estrutura simples para treinar o require, mas está apresentando erro. O que estou errando ?

Estrutura, dentro de C:\xampp_\htdocs\SMB\

```
/file_pasta_Root.php

/pasta_A/file_pasta_A.php

/app/pasta_B/file_pasta_B.php
```

Arquivos:

```
/file_pasta_Root.php
```

```
<?php
?>
<p>Eu sou o Arquivo que está no Root</p>
```

```
/pasta_A/file_pasta_A.php
```

```
<?php
require_once '../file_pasta_Root.php'
?>
<p>Eu sou o Arquivo que está na pasta A</p>
```

```
/app/pasta_B/file_pasta_B.php
```

```
<?php
require_once '../../pasta_A/file_pasta_A.php'
?>

<p>Eu sou o Arquivo que está na pasta B</p>
```

Então, quando acesso `https://localhost/smb/app/pasta_B/file_pasta_B.php` recebo um Fatal error, o que está errado ?

```
_______________
Warning: require_once(../file_pasta_Root.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp_\htdocs\SMB\pasta_A\file_pasta_A.php on line 2

_______________
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'../file_pasta_Root.php' (include_path='C:\xampp_\php\PEAR') in 
C:\xampp_\htdocs\SMB\pasta_A\file_pasta_A.php on line 2

___________
```

**Todavia**, Eu alterei os caminhos dos require para esse do exemplo do Arquivo: `file_pasta_A.php` e funcionou "mais ou menos", porém eu gostaria de saber se esse é o melhor método para corrigir o problema.

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../file_pasta_Root.php';
?>
<p>Eu sou o Arquivo que está na pasta A</p>
```

Comment: Ali. O erro está bem ali naquela linha 2.

Comment: Nesse caso a melhor abordagem é a que funcionar. Dessa forma: `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../file_pasta_Root.php';` funcionou? então maravilha.